# How to customize Identity controller for React SPA in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I followed official [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity-api-authorization?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for identity with SPA from microsoft. However right now I need more data in my user table. So I followed [customise identity tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-3.1) but that is for razor pages. Right now when I open my scaffolded react app, I can't see any controller to customise. I can add new data from the model, however how do I customise the controller for user register in react SPA?

[image]

Comment: Today, I also looking for a solution like your need after about 3 days. The solution will be like this https://youtu.be/MGCC2zTb0t4?t=1710

Answer (score 1):

You need customize existing interface of Identity:

[image]

For example:

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using shadow.Models;
using shadow.Shared;
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace shadow.Services
{

    public interface IUserService
    {

        Task<UserManagerResponse> RegisterUserAsync(RegisterViewModel model);
        Task<UserManagerResponse> LoginUserAsync(LoginViewModel model);
        Task<UserManagerResponse> LogoutUserAsync(LoginViewModel model);
        Task<UserManagerResponse> ConfirmEmailAsync(string userId, string token);
        Task<UserManagerResponse> ForgetPasswordAsync(string email);
        Task<UserManagerResponse> ResetPasswordAsync(ResetPasswordViewModel model);
    }

    public class UserService : IUserService
    {
        private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManger;
        private IConfiguration _configuration;
        private IMailService _mailService;

        public UserService(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IConfiguration configuration, IMailService mailService)
        {
            _userManger = userManager;
            _configuration = configuration;
            _mailService = mailService;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Đăng ký.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<UserManagerResponse> RegisterUserAsync(RegisterViewModel model)
        {
            if (model == null)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException("Reigster Model is null");
            }
            if (model.Password != model.ConfirmPassword)
            {
                return new UserManagerResponse
                {
                    Message = "Confirm password doesn't match the password",
                    IsSuccess = false,
                };
            }
            var identityUser = new ApplicationUser
            {
                Email = model.Email,
                UserName = model.Email,
                About = model.About,
                SecondMobile = model.SecondMobile,
                Fullname = model.Fullname,
                AliasName = model.AliasName,
                Created = DateTime.Now,
                Modified = DateTime.Now
            };
            var result = await _userManger.CreateAsync(identityUser, model.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                var confirmEmailToken = await _userManger.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(identityUser);
                var encodedEmailToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(confirmEmailToken);
                var validEmailToken = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(encodedEmailToken);
                string url = $"{_configuration["AppUrl"]}/api/auth/ConfirmEmail?userId={identityUser.Id}&token={validEmailToken}";
                await _mailService.SendEmailAsync(identityUser.Email, "Confirm your email", $"<h1>Welcome to Trustee app</h1>" +
                    $"<p>Please confirm your email by <a href='{url}'>clicking here</a></p>");
                return new UserManagerResponse
                {
                    Message = "User created successfully!",
                    IsSuccess = true,
                };
            }
            return new UserManagerResponse
            {
                Message = "User did not create",
                IsSuccess = false,
                Errors = result.Errors.Select(e => e.Description)
            };
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Đăng nhập.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="model"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task<UserManagerResponse> LoginUserAsync(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            var user = await _userManger.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return new UserManagerResponse
                {
                    Message = "There is no user with that Email address",
                    IsSuccess = false,
                };
            }
            var result = await _userManger.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (!result)
            {
                return new UserManagerResponse
                {
                    Message = "Invalid password",
                    IsSuccess = false,
                };
            }
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim("Email", model.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
            };
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["AuthSettings:Key"]));
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration["AuthSettings:Issuer"],
                audience: _configuration["AuthSettings:Audience"],
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
            string tokenAsString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            return new UserManagerResponse
            {
                Message = tokenAsString,
                IsSuccess = true,
                ExpireDate = token.ValidTo
            };
        }

        // Đăng xuất.
        public async Task<UserManagerResponse> LogoutUserAsync(LoginViewModel model)
        {
            var user = await _userManger.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return new UserManagerResponse
                {
                    Message = "There is no user with that Email address",
                    IsSuccess = false,
                };
            }
            var result = await _userManger.CheckPasswordAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (!result)
            {
                return new UserManagerResponse
                {
                    Message = "Invalid password",
                    IsSuccess = false,
                };
            }
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim("Email", model.Email),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id),
            };
            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["AuthSettings:Key"]));
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer: _configuration["AuthSettings:Issuer"],
                audience: _configuration["AuthSettings:Audience"],
                claims: claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(30),
                signingCredentials: new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256));
            string tokenAsString = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
            return new UserManagerResponse
            {
                Message = tokenAsString,
                IsSuccess = true,
                ExpireDate = token.ValidTo
            };
        }

        public async Task<UserManagerResponse> ConfirmEmailAsync(string userId, string token)
        {
            var user = await _userManger.FindByIdAsync(userId);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return new UserManagerResponse { IsSuccess = false, Message = "User not found" };
            }
            var decodedToken = WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(token);
            string normalToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedToken);
            var result = await _userManger.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, normalToken);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return new UserManagerResponse { Message = "Email confirmed successfully!", IsSuccess = true };
            }
            return new UserManagerResponse
            {
                IsSuccess = false,
                Message = "Email did not confirm",
                Errors = result.Errors.Select(e => e.Description)
            };
        }

        public async Task<UserManagerResponse> ForgetPasswordAsync(string email)
        {
            var user = await _userManger.FindByEmailAsync(email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return new UserManagerResponse { IsSuccess = false, Message = "No user associated with email", };
            }
            var token = await _userManger.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user);
            var encodedToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(token);
            var validToken = WebEncoders.Base64UrlEncode(encodedToken);
            string url = $"{_configuration["AppUrl"]}/ResetPassword?email={email}&token={validToken}";
            await _mailService.SendEmailAsync(email, "Reset Password", "<h1>Follow the instructions to reset your password</h1>" +
                $"<p>To reset your password <a href='{url}'>Click here</a></p>");
            return new UserManagerResponse
            {
                IsSuccess = true,
                Message = "Reset password URL has been sent to the email successfully!"
            };
        }

        public async Task<UserManagerResponse> ResetPasswordAsync(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
        {
            var user = await _userManger.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null)
            {
                return new UserManagerResponse { IsSuccess = false, Message = "No user associated with email", };
            }
            if (model.NewPassword != model.ConfirmPassword)
            {
                return new UserManagerResponse { IsSuccess = false, Message = "Password doesn't match its confirmation", };
            }
            var decodedToken = WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(model.Token);
            string normalToken = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decodedToken);
            var result = await _userManger.ResetPasswordAsync(user, normalToken, model.NewPassword);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return new UserManagerResponse { Message = "Password has been reset successfully!", IsSuccess = true };
            }
            return new UserManagerResponse
            {
                Message = "Something went wrong",
                IsSuccess = false,
                Errors = result.Errors.Select(e => e.Description)
            };
        }
    }

}
```